# jQuery disable textbox input for type number

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a HTML markup which looks like following:

```
 <input type="number"  step="0.1" min="0" max="100" value="1" class="form-control breakEvenInput" style="width:150px" /><br />
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary saveBreakEven">Save</button>
```

As you can see the input is of type "number"... What I was thinking (if it's possible) to do here is to disable the end user so that he/she is not able to input anything into the textbox, but rather enable the user just to have that side scrool up/down arrows that he gets when browser renders the HTML input as type of "number".

I've tried to add "disabled" or "readonly" properties to HTML input but that didn't give me the desired result. When I do it like that then the entire textbox is disabled...

I was thinking that this might be done somehow via jQuery? Can someone help me out ?

P.S. So i'd like to disable the input into the textbox via keyboard, but still leave the up/down arrows in textbox for the user to change the value, so that the user can't enter anything they want , let's say 99999999999 number.. ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263886/is-there-a-way-to-only-allow-input-using-the-spinner-controls-on-an-input-type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to ONLY allow input using the spinner controls on an input type="number"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263886/is-there-a-way-to-only-allow-input-using-the-spinner-controls-on-an-input-type)

Answer (score 1):

One of the things you can do is to prevent the **keydown event**.

```js
$(function() {

  $('input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" step="0.1" min="0" max="100" value="1" class="form-control breakEvenInput" style="width:150px" /><br />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary saveBreakEven">Save</button>
```

This way you keep the arrows active, but disable keyboard keys.
Inside the event object (e), you can also check what key was pressed (if you want to support backspace or arrows for example).

Answer (score 0):

An issue you will have is different browsers support and render type="number" differently.  I would suggest a span element for the number readout (ff you need to have it as an input, I would hide it), and use styled buttons or elements to increase, decrease the number and update the input box.  This will give a uniform user experience across browsers.

```
<!--style these how you want-->
<span id="number">0</span>
<button id="add>Up</button><button id="sub">Down</button>

<script>
    var step   = 1;
    var output = $('#number');
    var up     = $('#add');
    var sub    = $('#sub');

    up.add(sub).on('click', function() {
      var num = output.val();

      num += ( $(this).attr('id') == 'add' ) ? step : (-1 * step);
      if( isNumValid(num) ) {
        output.val(num);
      } else { <!-- error reporting here --> }

    }

    function isNumValid(num) {
      <!-- run validations here, integer, float, positive, etc -->
      return true/false;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

    $('input[type=number]').on('keydown', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```