# HTML number input min and max not working properly

Tags: html

I have `type=number` input field and I have set `min` and `max` values for it:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="23" value="14">
```

When I change the time in the rendered UI using the little arrows on the right-hand side of the input field, everything works properly - I cannot go either above 23 or below 0. However, when I enter the numbers manually (using the keyboard), then neither of the restrictions has effect.

Is there a way to prevent anybody from entering whatever number they want?

Comment: you can achieve restrcirion with the ehlp of js/jquery.

Comment: But always remember, you cannot restrict what will be sent back to your server. Inputs must always be validated on your side (as well).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With HTML5 `max` and `min`, you can only restrict the values to enter numerals. But you need to use JavaScript or jQuery to do this kind of change. One idea I have is using `data-` attributes and save the old value:

```js
$(function () {
  $("input").keydown(function () {
    // Save old value.
    if (!$(this).val() || (parseInt($(this).val()) <= 11 && parseInt($(this).val()) >= 0))
    $(this).data("old", $(this).val());
  });
  $("input").keyup(function () {
    // Check correct, else revert back to old value.
    if (!$(this).val() || (parseInt($(this).val()) <= 11 && parseInt($(this).val()) >= 0))
      ;
    else
      $(this).val($(this).data("old"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" min="0" max="23" value="14" />
```

Comment: This has massive failings. If you need to enter `23` for example, it won't allow you as it takes each `keydown` and therefore thinks you're entering just `2`. Also you can hold down one key for as long as you like i.e. `5555555` because there's no `keyup` caught.

Comment: @joel2703 This is two year old post, and do you think this would add value still? If so, please feel free to edit my answer and add your stuff.

Comment: There is a case when `input` is empty if you delete the value. So in the end of `$("input").keyup(function () {` we have to add `if (!$(this).val()) { $(this).val(0); }`

Comment: I know this is an old post. Yet it is still the accepted answer. Currently I cannot enter _any_ sensible two digit number into the input field apart from "11".

Answer (score 20):

Maybe Instead of using the "number" type you could use the "range" type which would restrict the user from entering in numbers because it uses a slide bar and if you wanted to configure it to show the current number just use JavaScript

Answer (score 19):

Despite the HTML5 enforcement of min and max on the up/down arrows of type=number control, to really make those values useful **you still have to use Javascript**.

Just save this function somewhere and call it on keyup for the input.

```js
function enforceMinMax(el) {
  if (el.value != "") {
    if (parseInt(el.value) < parseInt(el.min)) {
      el.value = el.min;
    }
    if (parseInt(el.value) > parseInt(el.max)) {
      el.value = el.max;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="23" value="14" onkeyup=enforceMinMax(this)>
```

Comment: While this might be useful in specific cases (like this one), its not very nice for the user as the value changes. For example, if you enter `111` it will become `23` when ideally it should stay in `11`. In other cases, as commented by @horiatu, it won't let you enter `15` if the minimum is set to `10`.

Comment: @lepe Exactly, I second you!

Comment: This works well for me in Angular. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

```html
<input type="number" min="0" onkeyup="if(value<0) value=0;" />
```

Comment: this is the best effective answer IMO.

Comment: This can be bypassed by using the up/down buttons...

Comment: It works even with up/down buttons in google chrome and microsoft edge, test yourself on other browsers.

Answer (score 13):

In some cases `pattern` can be used instead of `min` and `max`. It works correctly with `required`.

Comment: But you can still type and write all the characters that are not allowed.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="number"]').on('keyup',function(){
        v = parseInt($(this).val());
        min = parseInt($(this).attr('min'));
        max = parseInt($(this).attr('max'));

        /*if (v < min){
            $(this).val(min);
        } else */if (v > max){
            $(this).val(max);
        }
    })
})
```

Here is my contribution. Note that the v < min is commented out because I'm using Bootstrap which kindly points out to the user that the range is outside the 1-100 but wierdly doesn't highlight > max!

Answer (score 5):

```
oninput="if(this.value>your_max_number) this.value=your_max_number;"
```

This works properly for me.

Answer (score 3):

One `event listener`, No `data-` attribute.

You can simply prevent it by using following script:

```js
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[name=quantity]', function() {
  var _this = $(this);
  var min = parseInt(_this.attr('min')) || 1; // if min attribute is not defined, 1 is default
  var max = parseInt(_this.attr('max')) || 100; // if max attribute is not defined, 100 is default
  var val = parseInt(_this.val()) || (min - 1); // if input char is not a number the value will be (min - 1) so first condition will be true
  if (val < min)
    _this.val(min);
  if (val > max)
    _this.val(max);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" max="250" min="1" value="">
```

**The only problem is**: You can't type `-` to get negative numbers if your `min` is lower than 0

Answer (score 3):

This works for me I think you should try this you change the pattern according to your need
like you start from pattern 1

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{2}" min="0" max="23" value="14">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use html keyup event for restriction

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="23" value="14" onkeyup="if(value<0) value=0;if(value>23) value=23;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[type=number][min],input[type=number][max]', function () {
    var _this = $(this);
    if (_this.val() === "-")
        return;

    var val = parseFloat(_this.val());

    if (_this.attr("min") !== undefined && _this.attr("min") !== "") {
        var min = parseFloat(_this.attr('min'));

        if (val < min)
            _this.val(min);
    }
    if (_this.attr("max") !== undefined && _this.attr("max") !== "") {
        var max = parseFloat(_this.attr('max'));

        if (val > max)
            _this.val(max);
    }
});
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=number][step]', function () {
    var _this = $(this);

    var val = parseFloat(_this.val());

    if (_this.attr("step") !== undefined && _this.attr("step") !== "") {
        var step = parseFloat(_this.attr('step'));

        if ((val % step) != 0)
            _this.val(val - (val % step));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this range method instead of number method.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#input").change(function () {
    // Save old value.
    $("#limit").val($("#input").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="limit" name="limit" value="14" readonly><br>
<input type="range" id="input" name="input" min="0" max="23" value="14"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
  $("input").keydown(function () {
    // Save old value.
    if (!$(this).val() || (parseInt($(this).val()) <= 11 && parseInt($(this).val()) >= 0))
    $(this).data("old", $(this).val());
  });
  $("input").keyup(function () {
    // Check correct, else revert back to old value.
    if (!$(this).val() || (parseInt($(this).val()) <= 11 && parseInt($(this).val()) >= 0))
      ;
    else
      $(this).val($(this).data("old"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" min="0" max="23" value="14" />
```

Comment: You cannot write anything that is more than one number. [0:9]

Answer (score 0):

Forget the keydown or keyup: it won't let you enter like 15 or 20 if the min was set to 10!
Use the change event since this is where the input value goes in your business logic (ViewModel):

```
private _enforceMinMax = (input:HTMLInputElement) => {
    console.log("input", input);
    const v = parseFloat(input.value);
    if(input.hasAttribute("min")) {
        const min = parseFloat(input.min);
        if(v < min) {
            input.value = min+"";
        }
    }
    if(input.hasAttribute("max")) {
        const max = parseFloat(input.max);
        if(v > max) {
            input.value = max+"";
        }
    }
}

private _distanceChange = (event) => {
    this._enforceMinMax(event.target);
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This work perfect for geographic coordinates when you have general function document EventListener "keydown" in my example i use bootstrap class.

```
<input type="text" name="X_pos" id="X_pos" class="form-control form-control-line" onkeydown="event.stopPropagation(); return(parseInt(event.key) >= 0 && parseInt(event.key) <= 9 && this.value+''+event.key <= 179 && this.value+''+event.key >= (-179)) || this.value.slice(-1) == '.' && parseInt(event.key) >= 0 && parseInt(event.key) <= 9 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 190 && String(this.value+''+event.key).match(/\./g).length <=1 || event.keyCode == 109 && String(this.value+''+event.key).length == 1 || event.keyCode == 189 && String(this.value+''+event.key).length == 1" style="width:100%;" placeholder="X" autocomplete="off">
```

If you want you can create a function with this code but i preferred this method.

Answer (score 0):

Again, no solution truly solved my question. But combined the knowledge, it somehow worked

What I wanted is a true max/min validator (supporting int/float) for my input control without fancy html5 help

Accepted answer of @Praveen Kumar Purushothaman worked but its hardcoded min/max in the checking condition

@Vincent can help me dynamically validate the input field by max/min attributes but it is not generic and only validating the integer input.

To combine both answer
Below code works for me

```
function enforceMinMax(el){
  if(el.value != ""){
    if(parseFloat(el.value) < parseFloat(el.min)){
      el.value = el.min;
    }
    if(parseFloat(el.value) > parseFloat(el.max)){
      el.value = el.max;
    }
  }
}

$(function () {
    $("input").keydown(function () {
        enforceMinMax(this);
    });
    $("input").keyup(function () {
        enforceMinMax(this);
    });
});
```

For the DOM

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="1" step=".001" class="form-control">
```

Afterwards all my inputs are truly responsive on the min max attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to respect min and max if they are defined on an input type=number:

```
$(document).on("change","input[type=number][min!=undefined]",function(){if($(this).val()<$(this).attr("min")) $(this).val($(this).attr("min"))})
$(document).on("change","input[type=number][max!=undefined]",function(){if($(this).val()>$(this).attr("max")) $(this).val($(this).attr("max"))})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Vanilla JS approach of testing against the set `min` and `max` values of a given input element if they are set.

All `input.check` elements are included in the input check. The actual input check is triggered by the `change` event and *not* by `keyup` or `keydown`. This will give the user the opportunity to edit their number in their own time without undue interference.

```js
const inps=document.querySelectorAll("input.check");
inps.forEach(inp=>{
 // memorize existing input value (do once at startup)
 inp.dataset.old=inp.value;
 // Carry out checks only after input field is changed (=looses focus)
 inp.addEventListener("change",()=>{
   let v=+inp.value;
   // console.log(v,inp.min,inp.max,inp.dataset.old);
   if(inp.max!=""&&v>+inp.max || inp.min!=""&&v<+inp.min) inp.value=inp.dataset.old;
   else inp.dataset.old=inp.value;
 });
})
```

```html
<input class="check" type="number" min="0.1" max="23.4" value="14" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue but in my case i had a save button as well.n
People could enter a wrong number and after lost focus the value stays.

If the number was too low or too high then in that case the save button set it to its max or min value, (and then directly after that return, not yet saving it), i made save only work with valid values.

Not to save it was just a choice one could also directly save it.
Its just another way how one can solve it.

As I didn't want to mix javascript (which can solve this) with typescript. I do understand angular typescript gets compiled to javascript but thats another topic.

Also i am aware that with angular based forms you can solve this differently. (in my case it had to be on a form but wasnt part, of it but had some relations with it, i'll spare the details or a rare case)

Answer (score 0):

This code will remove the last digit enetered by user to keep the value in the range. In some cases it may be more helpful instead of jumping to MAX. For minimum I think still better to jump to MIN.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#minmax').on('keyup', function() {
    var inputValue = parseInt($(this).val());
    var minValue = parseInt($(this).attr('min'));
    var maxValue = parseInt($(this).attr('max'));

    if (inputValue < minValue) {
      $(this).val(minValue);
    } else if (inputValue > maxValue) {
      // Remove the last digit to bring the value within the range
      $(this).val(function(_, value) {
        return value.slice(0, -1);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="minmax" type="number" min="0" max="23" value="14" />
```

jquery compact form just in case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#minmax").on("keyup",function(){var a=parseInt($(this).val()),b=parseInt($(this).attr("min")),c=parseInt($(this).attr("max"));a<b?$(this).val(b):a>c&&$(this).val(function(a,b){return b.slice(0,-1)})})});
```

Vanilla JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){document.getElementById("minmax").addEventListener("keyup",function(){var e=parseInt(this.value),t=parseInt(this.min),n=parseInt(this.max);e<t?this.value=t:e>n&&(this.value=this.value.slice(0,-1))})});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can compare keyCode and return false if those keys aren't numbers

for e.g

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script>
      function handleKeyDown(e) {
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="23" value="14" onkeydown="handleKeyDown(event)" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -5):

if you still looking for the answer you can use input type="number".
min max work if it set in that order:
1-name
2-maxlength
3-size
4-min
5-max
just copy it

```
<input  name="X" maxlength="3" size="2" min="1" max="100" type="number" />
```

when you enter the numbers/letters manually (using the keyboard), and submit a little message will appear in case of letters "please enter a number" in case of a number out of tha range "please select a value that is no more/less than .."

Comment: This looks like a good solution, however I tried in a react `input` and got an error. Then checked the `input` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) and found out that `maxlength` and `size` aren't supported for `<input type="number" ...`

Comment: What? Does the order matter? How is this possible?