# allow only 0-100 percent values in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a percentage textbox. I want to enter values 0 to 100. Not more than 100 or negative values.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ySt7S/10/)

Please check this fiddle. Here, it is allowing only 2 digit values like 99 only and after 99 it is allowing number of decimals(99..........9999) like this. Need to allow only one decimal point and I can enter 100 also.

Note :

1. Can Enter 0 to 100 and not negative and not more than 100.00
2. After decimal I want to enter only 2 digits like, 99.99 only.
3. Do not allow negative values.
4. Allow only one decimal point like(9.99 or 99.99). Not (9.......9..9...80099 or 99.......9......9).

```html
<script>
  function check(e,value){
    //Check Charater
    var unicode=e.charCode? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    if (value.indexOf(".") != -1)if( unicode == 46 )return false;
    if (unicode!=8)if((unicode<48||unicode>57)&&unicode!=46)return false;
  }
  function checkLength(){
    var fieldVal = document.getElementById('txtF').value;
    //Suppose u want 3 number of character
    if(fieldVal < 100){
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      var str = document.getElementById('txtF').value;
      str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
      document.getElementById('txtF').value = str;
    }
  }
</script>
    
<input id="txtF" type="number" onKeyPress="return check(event,value)" onInput="checkLength()" />
<p id="s"></p>
```

Please help me how can I do this using `jQuery` or `JavaScript`.

Comment: in html? I want to restrict in jquery or javascript.

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/9d8ene7u/

Comment: Please check that fiddle. It is allowing more than 100 and n number of decimal point and negative value also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML number input min and max not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936352/html-number-input-min-and-max-not-working-properly)

Comment: To allow 100 just change this: `if(fieldVal < 100){` to 101!

Answer (score 1):

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ySt7S/132/) This solves it for now, but the use of step=0.01 may not be what you want. Setting the step to 0.01 allows us to check the validity state of the input.

The validitiy state is not updated an a "before" event so on an "after" event we rollback the input.

```
<input id="txtF" type="number" onInput="return check(event,value)" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" />

check = function (e,value){
    if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
        e.target.value = value.substring(0,value.length - 1);
        return false;
    }
    var idx = value.indexOf('.');
    if (idx >= 0 && value.length - idx > 3) {
        e.target.value = value.substring(0,value.length - 1);
        return false;            
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It is allowing upto 999. And its allowing negative value also. And after decimal point I cant able to enter any values.

Comment: HI @gerard Sexton thank you so much. Here I can't able to add decimal values. If I add decimal, its clear the text field. others are working. I just want t add decimal. Example (99.99 or 100) only 2 digit after decimal.

Comment: @sathishkumar I cant reproduce your error. I have tested in IE9, FF, Chrome. All accept 99.99 and 100.00

Comment: If i give dot(.) its clearing all values. Please check in fiddle.

Comment: Its perfectly working in IE. But its not working in chrome.

Comment: Could you please help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var point=false;
var count=0;
function check(e,value){

//Check Charater
debugger;
if(count==3)return false;
    var unicode=e.charCode? e.charCode : e.keyCode;

    if( unicode == 46 && point==true)
           return false;
    if( unicode == 46 && point==false)
    {
            point=true;
    }
    if (unicode!=8)if((unicode<48||unicode>57)&&unicode!=46)return false;
    if(point==true)count++;
}
function checkLength(){
var fieldVal = document.getElementById('txtF').value;
//Suppose u want 3 number of character
if(fieldVal <= 100){
    return true;
}
else
{
    var str = document.getElementById('txtF').value;
    str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
document.getElementById('txtF').value = str;
}
}
</script>

<input id="txtF" type="number" onKeyPress="return check(event,value)" onInput="checkLength()" />
    <p id="s"></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ySt7S/130/

Comment: If you type in 0 and click arrow down you can get negative values here... Also if you type in 100 and click arrow up it starts on 10, 11, 12, 13 etc. But yes, it doesn't allow you to type in 101 or -1!

Comment: once I enter any decimal value in text field, again I cant able to enter any value on the same field.