# Restrict a textbox to only integers between 1 and 99

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am trying to add a text box which accepts only integers between 1 and 99. I tried adding a number type element with min and max but that works only when changing the number using the ticker

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="99" />
```

May I know a better way to achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

I would like to immediately validate the input like may be by replacing the entry with an empty character.

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you looking for a JavaScript solution?  Do you want to *immediately* validate the input (i.e. as soon as it is typed) or only on form submission?

Comment: I would like to immediately validate the input like may be by replacing the entry with an empty character

Comment: Assuming you mean you want to validate the spinner clicks ***and manual user input***, your question is nearly identical to this: [HTML number input min and max not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936352/html-number-input-min-and-max-not-working-properly)

Comment: You can use an `onkeyup` listener to check and change the value right after the user typed something.

Comment: @Santi I can still quickly input out-of-range number and submit it with that solution

Comment: I don't consider it a bad question. It should work, but in reality each browser interprets that input in different ways. @Dolt, Maybe you can consider using an Slider: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-pricing-slider-donations. You also have a jQueryUI slider (http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/), it depends on which libraries you want to add to your site

Comment: @Dolt **Not allowing a user to enter a certain value into an input should be used for nothing other than UI/UX purposes.** If you're allowing users to submit things without any validation assuming your input restriction will restrict 100% of all cases, then you're I believe you're a bit misguided in the first place. Regardless of what restrictions you put on this input, you should write your code expecting that the user will find away around them, because there is always a way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to validate the input on a key event (such as `keyup`).  Here's an example that will clear out anything that's not an integer between 1 and 99.

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById('inputBox');

inputBox.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  inputBox.value = "" + inputBox.value;
  if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
    // if not an integer
    clearInput();
    return;
  }
  if (inputBox.value.toLowerCase() !== inputBox.value.toUpperCase()) {
    // if a letter
    clearInput();
    return;
  }
  if (parseInt(inputBox.value) < 1 || parseInt(inputBox.value) > 99) {
    // if value is not in the desired range
    clearInput();
    return;
  }
});

function clearInput() {
  // invalid entry -- clear out input box
  inputBox.value = "";
}

inputBox.focus(); // this is just for ease of testing
```

```html
<input id="inputBox" type="number" min="1" max="99" />
```

Comment: OP told me in the comments that this method isn't valid because the user can "quickly submit" after typing an out-of-range value, which I personally think is silly, but just a bit of information.

Comment: Not a problem. I've upvoted your answer regardless because I think it's the right one. It sounds almost like OP is using this as a method of validating/sanitizing form submission, which in itself hurts to even type.

Comment: @Santi Ouch... I'd hate to work with anything on that backend if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? This shouldn't allow for negative numbers, and you're restricted to only 2 characters.

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="99" maxlength="2" />
```

Comment: Good solution, but allows for negative number input.

Comment: You can still enter negative numbers (i.e. `-2`).